# laravel mix Error: Failed to find '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

Tags: nodejs, webpack, laravel-mix

recientemente importé la librería leaftlet via `npm i leaftlet`

la incluí en `resources/js/app.js` haciendo require

```
require('leaflet/dist/leaflet.js');
```

y luego los estilos en `resources/css/app.css` haciendo import

```
@import '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
```

todo bien hasta ahí, incluso el IDE detecta ambos archivos, los puedo abrir y ver, existen. pero a la hora de compilar usando `npm run prod` o `npm run dev`

obtengo el error

```
    ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Failed to find '~leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
  in [
    /var/www/html/resources/css
  ]
```

si quito la importación de los estilos css, funciona todo de maravilla

qué podría ser el problema?

Comment: Intenta importarlo en el html principal

Comment: ya tienes el modulo cargado en el postCss de laravel-mix?

Comment: @NicolasAldana no sabía de eso, supongo que no, investigaré de eso, gracias!